# Dropbox - how to disallow a folder to be uploaded?

Tags: dropbox

I'm using Dropbox to store my web developments, in order to work with several computers.

My problem is, I don't need all the cache files to be uploaded each time. It's not the size, but the time it takes to sync that bothers me.

Is there a way to prevent a specific folder to be uploaded to the Dropbox servers ?

Comment: @Sun sorry, but it doesn't answer my needs : I know about selecive Sync (Which allows to _download_ the directories I want on a specific computer, but I wanted to know whether I could prevent the _upload_ of these folder's content to Dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put files in the Dropbox folder but not upload it. You normally can't do that. You can, however; symlink/junction a non-Dropbox folder and put it in the Dropbox folder. Dropbox will sync the files once and then won't sync again unless you restart Dropbox. Dropbox treats symlinks/junctions this way to prevent runaway loops.